# Can I use PuppeteerSharp with a WebApplicationBuilder or a Http(test)Client in a unit test?

Tags: puppeteer, nunit, dotnet-httpclient

My goal is to make a unit test which basically compares a snapshot of the resulting HTML of my project with a pre-saved snapshot file, in order to spot differences when the code changes (and be able to decide whether these changes are desired)

The thing is, our HTML includes some javascript which is used to append some extra HTML based on certain criteria on load.
So ideally, I want to load the resulting TestClient into Puppeteer, get the desired page, have Puppeteer resolve the javascript, and check the resulting HTML with the JS resolved.

Is there any way I can insert my HttpClient directly into Puppeteer, or is there another way I can get my desired result?

I currently have a solution where the HTML itself is inserted into puppeteer, but this doesn't work as I lose all css and external javascript files.

```
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
        await using var app = builder.BuildWithFeatures();
        await app.StartAsync();
        var client = app.GetTestClient();

        var response = await client.GetAsync($"/test/url");
        var html = await response.Content.ReadAsHtmlDocument();

        using var browserFetcher = new BrowserFetcher();
        await browserFetcher.DownloadAsync();
        await using var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(
            new LaunchOptions { Headless = true });
        await using var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
        await page.SetContentAsync(html.Text, new NavigationOptions(){ WaitUntil = [WaitUntilNavigation.Networkidle2]});
        var resulthtml = await page.GetContentAsync();
```